# Get only array element from a variable of github action

Tags: yaml, github-actions

In github action file, I am running an AWS CLI command and storing the output of using set-ouput and reusing it in next step.

```
name: abc-name
id: abc
bash : |
   set-ouput name=opValue::$(aws ......command.....)

name: check
bash : echo ${{steps.abc.output.opValue}}
```

but the aws command's output is in the form of array like ["value"] and same is getting stored in variable opValue.

In my next "check step", I want to only fetch value of it, not the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select the first value of the `aws` command output and store only that as output:

```yaml
set-ouput name=opValue::$(aws ......command..... | jq '.[0]')
```